# Is there a way to modify a URL just before a page refreshes using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say we have a page with the URL `http://localhost/english/startsite`of which we have the following code to make the site url more readable:

```
(function () {
    var windowOriginalLocation = window.location;
    window.history.pushState("string", "Title", "home");

    $(window).bind("onbeforeunload", function () {
        window.history.pushState("string", "Title", windowOriginalLocation);
    });
})();
```

Every time this anonymous function runs for the page, it will rewrite the URL to `http://localhost/english/home` - which is what we want for our solution.

*The problem*

When the user presses F5 or Manually clicks the refresh button, one would expect that the `onbeforeunload` event would fire and restore the original url before refreshing the page - yet this does not happen and instead hits the brick wall called `HTTP Error 404 - Not Found`.

**How can I, using javascript/JQuery, restore the correct url so the browser navigates to the correct page on refresh?**

Comment: Are you using PHP at all?

Comment: actually no, this is a pure html running from IIS

Comment: You could write and distribute your own browser (I'd suggest SecurityHoleExplorer if you're looking for a brand name) ;-) Seriously though, wouldn't a DNS redirect be a better idea? (see http://superuser.com/a/559628)